# Setting href attribute at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the best way to set the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag at run time using jQuery?

Also, how do you get the value of the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag using jQuery?

Answer (score 379, accepted):

To get or set an attribute of an HTML element, you can use the [`element.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function in jQuery.

To get the *href* attribute, use the following code:

```
var a_href = $('selector').attr('href');
```

To set the *href* attribute, use the following code:

```
$('selector').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

In both cases, please use the appropriate selector. If you have set the class for the anchor element, use `'.class-name'` and if you have set the id for the anchor element, use `'#element-id'`.

Comment: I used this to get href.
alert($("#publish-link").attr("href"));

And it gave me alert "undefined".

Comment: it probably means that your publish-link is a class rather than an id. try : alert($(".publish-link").attr("href")); instead

Comment: @lakum4stackof: It'd help if you post the exact < a > tag you are using here :)

Comment: ahh sorry. you are right. I have applied class and I used '#' in jquery code. it worked with alert($(".publish-link").attr("href")); Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 18):

In jQuery 1.6+ it's better to use:

`$(selector).prop('href',"http://www...")` to **set** the value, and

`$(selector).prop('href')` to **get** the value

In short, `.prop` gets and sets values on the **DOM** object, and `.attr` gets and sets values in the **HTML**. This makes `.prop` a little faster and possibly more reliable in some contexts.

Comment: agree '.prop' will get full path like: http : //www.../index.html while .attr will get only: 'index.html'

Answer (score 14):

Set the `href` attribute with

```
$(selector).attr('href', 'url_goes_here');
```

and read it using

```
$(selector).attr('href');
```

Where "selector" is any valid jQuery selector for your `<a>` element (".myClass" or "#myId" to name the most simple ones).

Hope this helps !

Comment: I used this to get href. alert($("#publish-link").attr("href")); And it gave me alert "undefined".

Comment: @lakum4stackof you most likely executed that alert code BEFORE you set your `href` attribute, assuming your selector is correct.

Comment: try : alert($(".publish-link").attr("href")); as your element may be a class rather than an id. in fact, probably using $(this) if it's inside your event

Answer (score 2):

Small performance test comparision for three solutions:

1. `$(".link").prop('href',"https://example.com")`
2. `$(".link").attr('href',"https://example.com")`
3. `document.querySelector(".link").href="https://example.com";`

[image]

Here you can perform test by yourself https://jsperf.com/a-href-js-change

---

We can read href values in following ways

1. `let href = $(selector).prop('href');`
2. `let href = $(selector).attr('href');`
3. `let href = document.querySelector(".link").href;`

[image]

Here you can perform test by yourself https://jsperf.com/a-href-js-read

Comment: Nice!  Oddly, I am getting opposite results of you, but it is interesting to be able to run them myself.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger yes - very interesting - what is your machine, OS and browser ?

Comment: FF59, Win10.  The results seem to have slightly changed again (maybe it depends on # of tabs open), but still mostly the same: https://imgur.com/a/MLDnTWM Machine: 10-year old intel board (dp55wg), 3.1ghz quad-core, 16gb ddr3 ram, gtx1070.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
a:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link").click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr("href").split("#");
        $(".results").text(href[1]);
    })
})
</script>



<a class="link" href="#one">one</a><br />
<a class="link" href="#two">two</a><br />
<a class="link" href="#three">three</a><br />
<a class="link" href="#four">four</a><br />
<a class="link" href="#five">five</a>


<br /><br />
<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as answers that have working code plus helpful explanations. 
In this case, it would be worthwhile explaining this answer to a 5 year old.