# How to change Href for multiple Anchors within Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How does one change the HREF value of a table using the following

```
<table id="tbl">
<td>
<a href="1">test1</a>
<a href="2">test2</a> 
<a href="3">test3</a>
</td>
<td><label>foo1</label></td>
<td><label>foo2</label></td>
<td><label>foo3</label></td>
</table>
```

To this:

```
<table id="tbl">
<td>
<a href="1foo1">test1</a>
<a href="2foo2">test2</a> 
<a href="3foo3">test3</a>
</td> 
<td><label>foo1</label></td>
<td><label>foo2</label></td>
<td><label>foo3</label></td>
</td>
</table>
```

Essentially I am relabling the anchors based on data from another column. I would prefer to use jquery.
THanks!

Comment: This answer is also available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345427/jquery-set-and-get-href

Comment: No.  I know how to change the href. I don't know how to change it based on the other columns text.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#tbl td a").each(function() {
    var oldVal = $( this ).attr( "href" );
    $( this ).attr( "href" ,  oldVal + "foo" + oldVal);
});
```

Comment: Just beat me to it :( +1

Comment: this will only add **foo1** for all `href`; there will be no **foo2** and **foo3**

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$('#tbl td a').each(function(i) {
    var text = $('#tbl label').eq(i).text(),
        oldHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', oldHref + text);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amA8S/)**

---

If you want to remove the trailing spaces inside the text of your label, you can use **[$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)**:

```
$('#tbl td a').each(function(i) {
    var text = $('#tbl label').eq(i).text(),
        oldHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', oldHref + $.trim(text));
});
```

Comment: +1 for `eq()`. You can make it even more generic by using `$('label', $(this).closest('table'))` as a label selector, so it doesn't depend on the table's id.

Comment: This looks promising.  It works on IE8 but not on IE9.  IE9 gives me the right url but it adds spaces within the "text" variable.