# Error access variable form function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

In chrome function but in IE10 return error for the variable name in the function, how I can have access to this variable from the function?

```
  $('.kpit').on('click', function() {        
        var url = $(this).attr('id');
        var name = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.kpi').html('');
        $.post(url, {idKpi: id}, function(result) {
            $(name).html(result);
        });
  });
```

Comment: What does your error say?

Comment: Wait, you're trying to use the value of an `href` as a jQuery selector?

Comment: I´m using JQUery UI Tab, in the href have the value of the target div.

Comment: Also, which variable? `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 $('.kpit').on('click', function() {        
        var name = $(this).attr('id');
        var element = $(this); //Removed the .attr('href'), as that would store the URL, not the element.

        $('.kpi').html('');
        $.post(name, {idKpi: id}, function(result) {

        $(element).attr('href',result); //Set the HREF by using .attr, not .html
        });
  });
```

See [Setting href attribute at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345427/jquery-set-and-get-href)

Comment: I added a comment to the changed line. He was using $(name).html(result), but should try $(name).attr('href',result)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Missed that. Note @Andy's comment though: what *is* `$(name)` here?

Comment: How's this, now? I also changed the variable names, because he had url set to be the id value, and id set to be the href(url) value. Now it's just the name->id, and a new var element to use as a selector later instead of the old $(name).