# JQuery Manipulate Children of Div Set

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm working on creating a Greasemonkey script (JavaScript + JQuery) that reads data from the page. I'm presented with code like the following:

```
<div class="section">
     <div class="history-giveaway-name">
          <a href="www.google.com">Text!</a>
     </div>
     <div class="history-giveaway-state">
          // More stuff here
     </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
     <div class="history-giveaway-name">
          <a href="www.bing.com">Text!</a>
     </div>
     <div class="history-giveaway-state">
          // More stuff here
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get data from these divs. I have the div sections stored as a list, but I can't figure out how to get the div, for example, "history-giveaway-name". The end goal is to get data from the children, for example, the link from one of the hrefs.

Here's where I am so far, not sure where I'm going wrong. I get this error: "", but detected is always 3. JQuery methods like type() also don't work on sections[x].

```
var detected = 0;
var sections = $('[class$="section"]');
for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    editDialogText(sections[i].type());
    detected += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jquery, you can use `.each` to loop through and do something like:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0d9024d/1)

```
var detected = 0;
// Simplify how you specify the section class
var sections = $('.section');

sections.each(function () {
    // Get the URL within that section
    var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    console.log(link);
    detected +=1;
    console.log(detected);
});
```

Comment: this answer is correct. but you should use prop('href') instead of attr('href').
[from this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25557796/2348806)

Comment: @Sarin Suriyakoon It depends on what the user needs. If the user wants the literal attribute value as specified in the html, `.attr()` is useful. If the user needs the full http url, `.prop()` works.

Comment: How would I get a child by classname using this method? Still find?

Comment: @dwreck08 Thank you,sir. I love your answer which point to the user perspective. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: @ShadowDisruptor what do you mean exactly? Could you give more detail? if you mean each method **[Please check this out](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**

Comment: @ShadowDisrupter There are a few different ways of targeting children. You can use `.find()` or you can simply do it like a css selector `$('.section .history-giveaway-name')`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve. I replicated your code in jsfiddle and receive no error: https://jsfiddle.net/fezhvm71/

This is what I got:

```
Text!
// More stuff here
Text!
// More stuff here
```