# jQuery Get Value of data Attribute

Tags: jquery

I tried several times now changing the code. But every time I get NaN ...

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.ytdl').click(function() {
        var v = $(this).data('href');
        var f = $(this).data('format');

        alert(v + f);

    });
});


<a data-href="KMU0tzLwhbE" data-format="1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class="ytdl">Download</a>
```

But why? I tried already also changing data to attr.
But nothing of this is working.

Comment: This works exactly as planned - load it into a code snippet and try it - there must be something else going on somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `load` to `ready`

> The .ready() method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate. This will often be a good time to perform tasks that are needed before the user views or interacts with the page, for example to add event handlers and initialize plugins. When multiple functions are added via successive calls to this method, they run when the DOM is ready in the order in which they are added. As of jQuery 3.0, jQuery ensures that an exception occuring in one handler does not prevent subsequently added handlers from executing.
>   -- https://api.jquery.com/ready/

So here's a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/e89gh5Lk/

- document.ready is a jQuery event, it runs when the DOM is ready, e.g. all elements are there to be found/used, but not necessarily all content.
- window.onload fires later (or at the same time in the worst/failing cases) when images and such are loaded, so if you're using image dimensions for example, you often want to use this instead.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem : ) Simple but works haha

Comment: @LenaLuther please mark it as a correct answer by clicking on the check :)

Comment: @dyaa This is the reason I don't bother giving answers to people with 1 rep.

Comment: @dyaa ok : ) something else - when I want to change the "value" or "html" or "href" from THAT specific <a href with data-href="XY">.... how can I catch it.. I mean when I want to change the href of this specific link with data-href="XY"

Comment: @LenaLuther check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4345455/1132405