# Setting element href value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

There are a few posts on this already, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345427/setting-href-attribute-at-runtime) which couldn't be more simple to follow. For some reason though I can't get the element to link to the href attribute.

This is the class for the element that needs to be linked: `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(1)`;

There is an anchor on the page **#about**;

This is the jQuery I'm using:

```
<script>
jQuery('.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(1)').prop('href','https://example.com/#about');
</script>
```

The idea is to use the `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(1)` element to link to the **/#about** section on the page.

Please can someone help me correct what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use `attr` in place of `prop`

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR thanks, I tried that and unfortunately it also doesn't work

Comment: In what way is it not working?  What console errors are you getting?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I'm getting `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #` see here: https://s23.postimg.org/45fww8kaj/Screen_Shot_2017-07-05_at_21.05.19.png

Comment: that screenshot won't help... you need to provide more code, this code is not the issue here... this works fine

Comment: @KarthikGanesan what code is missing? Other than the class of the element, the href link and the JS what's left? There's no CSS involved and the HTML is built from a VC tab element which outputs the class `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(1)`, there isn't really anything else to show, please let me know what's missing if you know/can speculate?

Comment: @VDesign from what you have provided it works fine here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/9/ but the error you provided has to come from some other location in your file

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I've got the URL to show up in the bottom corner (URL preview Chrome) by adding `a` to `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(1)` to make `.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(1) a`, but for some reason the link doesn't work - i.e nothing happens when I click

Comment: @VDesign you mean by adding a to ".vc_tta-tab" and not ".vc_tta-tab:nth-child(1)"

Comment: @KarthikGanesan nooo, I mean what I said, this is my current JS: `<script>
jQuery('.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(1) a').attr('href','http://example.com');
</script>`

Comment: @VDesign try this instead jQuery('.vc_tta-tab:first(1)').prop('href','https://example.com/#about');

Comment: @KarthikGanesan thanks, unfortunately this stopped the link from showing up again in the status bar, I tried adding `a` again to `jQuery('.vc_tta-tab:first(1)').prop('href','example.com/#abo‌​ut');` and the link came back again in the status bar but no link functionality, quite strange really :/

Answer (score 0):

VDesign is right about using `attr` instead of `prop`. For your URL I think you might need the actual page to use the anchor. Like `http://example.com/index.html#about` instead of `http://example.com/#about`.

Comment: it works even with prop... the issue lies somewhere else in his code here is a working fiddle with prop https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/9/

Comment: Ah, so it does. I was trying to figure out where his syntax error was coming from in the other thread (I don't have the rep yet to comment on others' answers).