# Create HTML link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks to quick help this is solved:

**HTML**

```
<a id="myid" href="#">What ever goes here</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#myid").attr("href");
```

---

I need a HTML link created using jQuery. The link is on an image.
I need to get the actual site url only and get that into the href of the link.

```
<a href=" + the link created from jQuery + "><img src="myimage.jpg" /></a>
```

I have found some helpfull similar questions but they all ended on an OnClick event, e.g. with a button or so. I don't want a button but the anchorlink created on page load.
I have done a little JavaScript ages ago and jQuery is quite new for me.

Though i managed to get this object for which i need an example for and also how I load it into the anchorlink.

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

Comment: So I'm unclear as to what you want the href value to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting href attribute at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345427/setting-href-attribute-at-runtime)

Comment: I need the actual url of the site the visitor is on and not a static url. Does this clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.yoursite.com")
```

This will set `href` attribute for all the `a` tag.

**OR**

```
$("#myid").attr("href", "http://www.yoursite.com/")
```

If you set `id=myid` for the `a` tag.

***Make sure you add jQuery in your code.***

Comment: Of course it is the "id" attribute i was looking for! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery**

```
var $link = $("<a></a>");                          // Creates the link element.
$link.attr("href", "https://WhateverYouWant.com"); // Sets the href attribute to a particular link.
$("body").append($link);                           // Adds the link to the bottom of your page.
```

**JavaScript**

```
var link = document.createElement("a");                      // Creates the link element.
link.setAttribute("href", "https://WhateverYouWant.com");    // Sets the href attribute to a particular link.
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(link);  // Adds the link to the bottom of your page.
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you click the button in the example you get links to the images :) Enjoy!

```js
$( '#myButton' ).click( function() {

  $('img').each( function(i,e) {
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    $(link).attr('href', $(e).attr('src'));
    $(link).append( $(e).clone() );
    $(e).replaceWith( link );
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x200">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
<br/>
<button id="myButton">Make links for images!</button>
```

If you want to get the images to be decorated with links on pageload use the `img each` within a `$(document).ready(function...)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to put the current page url into the link, you just need to grab it.

```
var pageUrl = window.location.href;
var newLink = '<a href="'+ pageUrl +'"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></a>';

//do whatever you want with newLink
```